# NSArray Manipulation

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How can I store the values from index 1 of my array into another array.

[image]

Comment: Really?  That is a rather basic question...

Comment: How? Sorry a bit groggy

Comment: `[otherArray addObject:thisArray[1]];`

Comment: Throwing exception at thisArray[1] even at index 0, even at values objectAtIndex:0

Comment: Number of elements in array = 1, when i print values count

Comment: That's not index 1 then, is it.

Comment: When I change the index to 0, my other array is nil. Which is weird

Comment: So you have to allocate it first.  You really are asking basic questions.  Get some training/do some reading before jumping in with both feet.

Answer (score 0):

Take count of your array in to a variable i
int i=[yourarray count]
make a forloop till the count-1 and add these to new array

[NewArray addObject:[yourarray objectatIndex:i]];

Comment: The problems is when I    NSLog (@"Number of elements in array = %lu", [values count]); it returns only 1.  Number of elements in array = 1

Comment: From your image it seems like  its a combination of NSArrays and NSDictonaries. could you please add output of command  here NSlog(@"%@",yourarray);

Comment: because the way we retrieve from array and dictonary is diff.  We use index for arrays and keys for dictonaries.you need to go through some basic tutorials first